# Array Length in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am new to coding so I apologize if this is a dumb question.  I am writing values to an array such that the position in the array corresponds to the value, such that the first position in the array is 1, the second position in the array is 2 the nth position in the array has a value of n.  This code works up until you input 8.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int a = 0, b = 0;

int main(void){  
    int die[b];
    printf("Input how many sides your die has \n");
    scanf("%i", &b);    
    for(a = 1; a <= b; a++){
        die[a] = a;
    }    
    for(a = 1; a <= b; a++){
        printf("%i  ", die[a]);
    }
}
```

However, this code works for any value inputted....

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 0,b = 0;

int main(void){
    printf("Input how many sides your die has \n");
    scanf("%i", &b);
    int die[b];
    for(a = 1; a <= b; a++){
        die[a] = a;
    } 
    for(a = 1; a <= b; a++){
        printf("%i  ", die[a]);
    }
}
```

My question is why does changing the position of the scanf, and the declaration of the array change the way the code works so much?

Comment: Arrays in C are *zero-indexed* (e.g. they start at `0`), so you are writing from the second element `1` to *1-past the end of your array* with `for(a=1; a <= b; a++); die[a] = a`. Say if the user enters `6`, your valid elements are `0-5`. In your case, you would need adjust your index (e.g. `for(a=0; a < b; a++)`) You can then adjust the array as needed (e.g. `die[a] = a + 1;`) or whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

Both code samples lead to Undefined Behavior. Array index should start from `0`. Your loop should be like this:

```
for(a=0; a < b; a++){
```

In your first code sample `int die[b];`  b is initialized to 0. Its only after the scanf it gets initialized to user defined input.

Also the format specifier for `int`s is `%d`.

Answer (score 1):

All of the above answers already have told that your code is leading to a undefined behavior. Will to to clarify things further.
Basically your array is a local variable with static size. So it will be allocated on stack. So when you say int arr[b] while b is zero at compile time arr[0] is allocated on the stack.
The scanf works at runtime. So when you scanf a value in 'b' that wont go back in the stack and resize the array. So if you want dynamic array, i.e. allocate array at runtime following code might serve you best.

```
int a = 0, b = 0;
int main()
{
 int* arr = NULL;
 printf("How many sides does your dice has?\n");
 scanf("%d", &b);

 arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*b);

 for(a = 0; a < b; a++)
 {
  arr[a] = a;
 }
}
```

Comment: Correct! variable length array's take variable which do not change at runtime +1.

Answer (score 0):

The first code actually leads to undefined behaviour. The reason is that you declare a global variable `b` initialized to `0` and then you create a local array `die[b]`, ***before*** reading a value from the user. So actually your array is created using value `0` for `b` and it will be declared as `die[0]`, in other words it is an array of size `0`. (Actually even when you read `b` using `scanf()`, this is a different variable from the global `b` you have declared.)

In your second code, you do not need the global variable `b`. Make it local and read it from the user as you do.

- Moreover, when printing integers use the specifier `%d`.
- Finally, start indexing your array from `0`, not from `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, position of `scanf` will change the behavior of your code because in the first code value of b will be 0 and that's why your array will initialize like `die[0]` and in the second code value of b will be entered by user that's why array will initialize based on the user value.

Answer (score 0):

Array index start from `0` instead of `1`.

You can enter values into array like this.

```
for( a = 0; a < b; a++ ) {
    die[a] = a;
}
```

And you take output from array in similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

```
int die[b];

printf("Input how many sides your die has \n");
scanf("%i",&b);
```

here, initially ***b*** is 0. So you are declaring array of size 0. It is getting undefined behavior actually. But,

```
printf("Input how many sides your die has \n");
scanf("%i",&b);


int die[b];
```

here, you firstly taking value of ***b***. And then declaring array of size that ***b***.But still it will show undefined behavior, as you are trying to access ***die[b]***, where you have right to access from ***die[0]*** to ***die[b-1]*** (total b size).

Answer (score 0):

You should always think about the scope when you declare the variables. Below points you can try:

1. The variables `a` and `b` should be local variables.
2. You must learn about dynamic memory allocation in C. As I can see that after `scanf()` you want to create an array of size scanned. This is use case of dynamic memory allocation. So you need to use `malloc` to allocate an array of desired size.

After applying these fixes your program will rock :) and don't forget to `free` the memory - As a good programming practice.